# Mercurial: cross-version merges / massive cherry-picking

Tags: version-control, merge, mercurial, cherry-pick

### Situation

We have 2 versions (1.0 and 2.0) of a project that are both actively maintained. It is basically the same project (as far as changes go), but being based on different base versions (base1.0 and base2.0). Everything that is changed in 1.0 has also to be ported to 2.0. The same goes for base1.0 and base2.0.

In mercurial we have 4 branches: **base1.0**, **1.0**, **base2.0** and **2.0**. Something like this:

```
                         __2.0
             __base2.0__/
            /
__base1.0__/___1.0____________
```

Now everytime we change something in the base version, we make the change in **base1.0** and do a hg merge to **base2.0**. No problems here.

Now when we do the same for **1.0** and want to merge them into **2.0**, we also have to re-merge the entire **base1.0** branch into **2.0**, although that has already been done creating **base2.0** out of **base1.0**.

### Question

What is the most efficient way to solve this? I had a few approaches:

1. **Merge**: as explained above, this causes a lot of overhead and work to be re-done that has already been done
2. **graft** aka cherry-pick: Select every single change we make on **1.0** and port them to **2.0** using hg graft. While it does work in some cases, it creates duplicate changesets because it ports them 1:1. What I'd like would be 1 single commit containing all updates made on **1.0** grafted to **2.0**.
3. **diff export**: I also tried to make a export a diff between the original **1.0** and the most recent **1.0** and then import it onto **2.0**. But it's a patch, and patches are evil. And not very handy to handle.

Any ideas? Being relatively new to the whole SCM concept I just wanted to hear what others do in such scenarios. Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what happens during merge? Mercurial should not have to redo things that have been merged before.

Comment: I think the issue is that 2.0 has no direct relation to 1.0, so merging it tries to merge base1.0 into 2.0 again, having base1.0 as the only common ancestor. Conflicts that have been solved in creating base2.0 have to be solved again.

Comment: Have you looked at this way of organizing branches? https://andy.mehalick.com/2011/12/24/an-introduction-to-hgflow

Comment: I don't think I understand why this would solve my problem. I would still have to have 2 'master' branches because there are two different versions that continue to exist side-by-side for a fairly long time, no?

Comment: Yes, but I think one of your problems is that you're trying to merge the entire 1.0-branch into 2.0. You should instead try to create separate branches for new features, root them way back in your history where things are not so different between 1.0 and 2.0, and then merge them into both 1.0 and 2.0. But it's hard to say because I still don't know what kind of merge problems you're encountering, or why Mercurial is behaving like that. If you've dealt with a merge problem, merging more between the same branches should not bring those problems up again.

Comment: Suppose I got some conflicts by merging the changes in <FileA> from **base1.0**'s changes into **base2.0**. If I later on merge some changes in <FileB> from **1.0** to **2.0** the same conflict in <FileA> pops up again, even if I did not change <FileA> on branch **1.0**, only <FileB> That's the main issue I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually resolved my problem. I'll add it as an answer, maybe someone else finds it useful.

What I really needed was cherry-picking all my changes from **1.0** to **2.0**. hg graft does that pretty well, but creates an additional commit on **2.0** for each changeset grafted and messes up my graph.

So what I did was creating a clone of my repo and then grafting all the changesets using hg graft from **1.0** onto **2.0**. Then I exported a diff of pre-graft and post-graft and imported that diff as a patch onto the original repo.

Essentially a cumulative "graft" without any information about where it came from. This was exactly what I needed and worked for me in this case.

Comment: Ps: afterwards I committed a "logical" merge usig hg debugsetparent to keep track of up to where in **1.0** changes are included in **2.0**.